# AUTH_CHALLENGE and AUTHENTICATE

Tags: protocol

Can someone explain the purpose of the AUTH_CHALLENGE command in the Tor specification? As far as I understand, responding with an AUTHENTICATE cell is optional. When would it be desirable for a node to AUTHENTICATE?